# How to write a check constraint to disallow empty varchar fields?

Tags: sql-server, constraint

On SQL Server not nullable varchar columns can hold empty strings.

Under ORACLE they can't, because varchar2 treat '' as equivalent to NULL.

If you design a database schema suitable for both RDBMS it seems to be a good idea to add to each not nullable varchar column on SQL Server a constraint which disallows empty strings.

But which is the best way to formulate such a constraint?

I started with

```
if OBJECT_ID('varchar_without_empty_cols') > 0 drop table varchar_without_empty_cols
go

create table varchar_without_empty_cols (
id int ,
val varchar(10) not null CHECK (val <> '') 
)
go


insert into varchar_without_empty_cols values (1, ' ')  -- this ought be OK
go
insert into varchar_without_empty_cols values (2, '')   -- this has to violate the check
go
insert into varchar_without_empty_cols values (3, null) -- this violates the not null
go 

select * from varchar_without_empty_cols
```

But this constraint not only inhibits empty strings, which is intended, but it also inhibits strings consisting of a single character, and that is not what I intend.

Comment: SQL Server disregards trailing spaces, which is why a single space would still violate the constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To allow strings containing only spaces but disallow empty strings you can use

```
CREATE TABLE varchar_without_empty_cols
  (
     id  INT,
     val VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (DATALENGTH(val) > 0)
  )
```

Comment: +1 But I'm curious if there other ways to write this constraint.

Comment: @bernd_k - `CHECK (val LIKE '_%' ) `

Comment: It seems that both Oracle and SQL-Server need special treatment to identify empty strings.

Comment: @Martin: I suppose that `CHECK (val > '' )` would not work either in SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube CHECK (val > '' ) doesn't work in SQL-Server.